# Llamar un programa en Erlang desde C

Tags: c, linux, erlang

Buenos días,

Mi duda es que si alguien sabe como ejecutar un programa en Erlang desde un programa en C, además de pasarle desde C un parámetro a una función en dicho programa. Estoy trabajando en ambiente Linux.

Con respecto a que he buscado y que en encontrado, pues lo que he podido encontrar es como llamar a un programa .exe de Windows desde C.

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar y que esta pregunta no sea cerrada por ser muy amplia o no entenderse lo que pregunto, pues pienso que es un tema muy concreto y que no se basa en opiniones ni nada por el estilo.

De ante mano muchas gracias y ojalá puedan ayudarme.

Comment: ¿ A que te refieres con *llamarlo* ? Para ejecutar un programa, tienes `system( )` o la familia `execXX( )`. ¿ O quieres usar _erlang_ como si fuera un _script_ interno de tu programa ?

Comment: pues tengo un programa en erlang, con funciones totalmente aparte de C, y deseo ejecutar este programa erlang en cierto momento desde C.